# How to execute InitializeComponent without blocking UI thread in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want to open Window B from Window A, inside a Button click event, as follows:

```
MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();
mainWin.Show();
```

The problem is that in MainWindow constructor there's the InitializeComponent method and some others, and it takes a couple of seconds to execute, blocking the UI (I have a spinning icon and it doesn't spin).

Here's what I've tried:

```
await Task.Run(() => mainWin = new MainWindow()); // Exception: thread must be STA :(
```

and

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => mainWin = new MainWindow()));
```

and

```
await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async delegate {
    mainWin = new MainWindow();
}));
```

**EDIT: This is how MainWindow constructor looks like:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // Takes about 3 seconds...
}
```

By no means I'm a C# or WPF or threading expert, I found those "solutions" and I just tried them with no success. I want to know if there's a way to execute InitializeComponent async or how to keep my animation playing.

I'm using C# WPF (no MVVM) and .NET Framework 4.6. Thank you in advance.

Comment: InitializeComponent is meant to only perform lightweight UI setup. What are you doing that takes seconds to execute?

Comment: The short answer is 'move that stuff out of `InitializeComponent`'.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm using a library called FluentWPF [link](https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF) and it seems like it's not that well optimized.

Comment: That `something` in the constructor (hopefully set after `InitializeComponent()`) can most probably be sent to a Task, while keeping the Window hidden. The animation code/logic is undefined here.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, I mitigated the execution time by doing that, but still, InitializeComponent() is what takes the most time.

Comment: Than you have something there that shouldn't be. Images? Something that comes from a Network lookup? Move any of these associations to a method that executes *later* (your Window will be hidden, anyway).

Comment: @Jimi It might be, but the thing is that eventually they will have to load up at some point?, so I thought I could load everything up while playing that little spinning icon animation.

Comment: Yes, and they will load on your terms, using some dedicated async method. Leave the Window initializer work on its own.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, but the thing here is that I never touched InitializeComponent(). The reason why it takes so long is because I'm using a library called [FluentWPF](https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF), and judging by VS output window loading that assembly up takes ~3 seconds.

Comment: I don't know that package. It is loading its resources in a `Resource Dictionary` in your `App.xaml`. You'll have to investigate whether it can be setup in a different way.

Answer (score -1):

You can create window in another thread. The downside is that any access to that window's controls from main thread must be done via Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {             

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        void ThreadProc()
        {
            //create second window in background thread
            Window window2 = new Window2();
            window2.Show();

            //start WPF message loop
            DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();            
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //start background thread
            Thread thread2;
            thread2 = new Thread(ThreadProc);
            thread2.IsBackground = true;
            thread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread2.Start();
        }  

    // To access Window2 from MainWindow, do like that:
    //window2.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { window2.Title = "Hello, world"; });    

    }    
}
```

Comment: Proposing to throw threads at a single-threaded problem accomplishes one thing only: Multiplying the amount of problems you need to solve.